# Insert variable number of items with FORMAT ( )

Tags: python-3.x, format

I have a text with some strings that I want to replace with a variable. For example:

```
message = """I am a message for {user} and you have puchased the following items {items} with color {color}"""
```

There I want to replace `{user}, {items}` and `{color}` by a variable using the following code:

```
message = message_template.format(user='Ali', ID = ID1)
```

The problem is that in some cases I will have one item and in other cases more than 5 and I need to insert them independently. Also, `color` and `item` are part of a Dataframe.

Any idea about how could I insert a changing number of variables with `.format( )`?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by color and item are part of a dataframe ? Are you iterrating on a dataframe ?

Answer (score 1):

As for multiple items convert your list to a string using :  `', '.join(items)`

```
items = ['i1','i2','i3']
message = message_template.format(user='Ali', items = ', '.join(items), color='orange')
```